# How do I get rid of routing/controller logs from my RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

when I run RSpec, I 've got some unwanted controller / routing logs I want to get rid of.

How do I get rid of those?

```
rspec
Run options: include {:focus=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}

Randomized with seed 61970
....Processing by Api::CommentsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"comment"=>{"content"=>"Attempt to edit comment."}, "id"=>"28"}
Filter chain halted as :find_comment rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
.Processing by Api::CommentsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"comment"=>{"content"=>"Editing is nice"}, "id"=>"29"}
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)
.Processing by Api::CommentsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"comment"=>{"content"=>"Attempt to edit someone else's comment."}, "id"=>"30"}
Filter chain halted as :find_comment rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
.Processing by Api::CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"comment"=>{"subject_id"=>"201", "subject_type"=>"Card", "content"=>"This is so useful!"}}
Completed 200 OK in 41ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 9.2ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

1.You can write a filter like this:

```
def silence_action
  Rails.logger.silence do
    yield
  end
end
```

And add following line at your rspec so that your logger gets silenced:

```
RSpec.describe BaseController, :type => :controller do
  controller.class.around_filter :silence_action, :only => :action
end
```

2.Another way of silencing your logger would be writing a custom logger:

```
# lib/custom_logger.rb
 class CustomLogger < Rails::Rack::Logger
   def initialize  app, opts = {}
    @app = app
    @opts = opts
    @opts[:silenced] ||= []
  end

  def call  env
    if @opts[:silenced].include?(env['PATH_INFO']) || @opts[:silenced].any? {|silencer| silencer.is_a?( Regexp) && silencer.match( env['PATH_INFO']) }
      Rails.logger.silence do
        @app.call env
      end
    else
      super env
    end                        
  end
    end
```

Then at your rspec you can call a function that is responsible for switching logger:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib/custom_logger.rb'

  def use_custom_logger
    Rails.application do
      config.middleware.swap Rails::Rack::Logger, CustomLogger, :silenced => ["/noisy/action.json"]
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it seems this should be doable with a config option, or..?

Comment: @hakunin, I have updated my answer with another solution, let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Where do you put the second bit exactly?

Comment: Of what? What do you mean by `rspec controlller`.

Comment: I mean at where you were testing your controller at rspec. updated my answer again.

Comment: Got it, although I'd have to put that in every spec and thats not practical.